# Video fullscreen exit causing scroll position to change

Tags: firefox, html5-video, html5-fullscreen

I've encountered an issue with Firefox specifically (I'm using version 61.0.1 (64-bit)) where upon exiting the fullscreen of a video element on a page which is scrolled down it will caused the scrollTop of the body to return to an incorrect position.

Example code to test would be like (where `...` are multiple elements causing the page to be long):

```
<p>1</p>
<p>2</p>
<p>3</p>
...
<p>7</p>
<p>8</p>
<p>9</p>
<p><video src="https://www.w3schools.com/htmL/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4" loop="loop" controls></video></p>
<p>10</p>
<p>11</p>
<p>12</p>
...
<p>19</p>
<p>20</p>
<p>21</p>
<p><video src="https://www.w3schools.com/htmL/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4" loop="loop" controls></video></p>
```

Example fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/webbm/p8ws3yc9/

In my example I've tried to keep the HTML to some very basic elements so as not to introduce CSS related issues.

On the example above:

- Upon exiting the first video's fullscreen, the scrollTop of the body is in the correct place.
- Upon exiting the *second* video's fullscreen, the scrollTop of the body is moved upwards.
- This behaviour still occurs even if there is only the second video element, so I don't believe it's related to having more than one video element present.

Is this a known issue with a work-around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've taken this to Mozilla as a bug under https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1479262 and they are investigating.